# No add article button in mean.js?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, mean

I downloaded the latest version of mean.js on github: https://github.com/meanjs/mean

But to my great surprise, they seeem to have removed the add article option in the menu dropdown...

Is this normal ? Should I download another version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that option is still available. In MEAN.js only accounts with admin rights can create a new article. The account that you used to login in MEAN.js app probably doesn't have admin rights.

You have 2 options, depending on what you want to achieve:

1) Add 'admin' to your account `roles` property (which right now is `roles: ['user']` and should be `roles: ['user', 'admin']`).

or

2) Change the articles policy file located in `/modules/articles/server/policies/articles.server.policy.js` to allow normal users to create a new article:

```
...
, {
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: '*' // instead of ['get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: '*' // instead of ['get']
    }]
  },
...
```